# Leaflet 2.0.0 choropleth not showing (dashArray error)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm using the `leaflet` and `shiny` packages to create interactive maps in a web browser (Chrome). When updating `leaflet` from version 1.1.0 to version 2.0.0 some choropleth maps stopped showing correctly: most if not all of the polygons failed to show. What makes it more bizarre is that R is not showing any errors or warnings.

**What I expected**

[image: Choropleth map as I expected it]

**What I got**

[image: Choropleth not showing correctly]

I'm quite certain the error has to do with the new `leaflet` version, as this program was running fine before the update and has not been altered since (except for a small fix, related to [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/534)).

**Session info**

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.2-7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3  tools_3.4.3     grid_3.4.3      lattice_0.20-35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by eliminating all mentions of `dashArray` in the `addPolygons` function.

In the code below I eliminated the line `dashArray = "",`

```
leafletProxy("map") %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = sp,
        stroke = FALSE,
        fillOpacity = 0.9,
        smoothFactor = 0.5,
        color = colors,
        group = "Analysis",
        highlight = highlightOptions(
          weight = 10,
          color = "#666",
          dashArray = "",
          fillOpacity = 1,
          bringToFront = TRUE,
          stroke = FALSE
        ),
        label = label
      ) %>%
      addLegend(
        position = "bottomright",
        pal = colorPalette,
        values = colorValues,
        layerId = "legendColors",
        title = legendTitle
      )
```

Somehow this `dashArray` causes an error in javascript (?). Anyway when looking at the console in my browser I got the following error, which was the clue to solve the issue.

[image: dashArray error]

I hope this helps others to solve this very cryptic error!